# querySelector on custom elements won't work in external files

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselector

So I have this code:-

```js
const extendCSS = (el1, el2) =>{
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector(el1).attributes).forEach(function(item) {
    el2.setAttribute(item.name, item.value);
  });
}
const build = (elementType) => tag => {
  const query = document.querySelectorAll(tag);
  query.forEach(ptag => {
    const shadow = ptag.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const element = document.createElement(elementType);
    element.innerHTML = ptag.innerHTML;
    extendCSS(tag, element);
    element.setAttribute('id', tag);
    shadow.host.parentNode.replaceChild(element, shadow.host);
  });
};
const h1 = build('h1');
const textarea = build('textarea');
textarea("text-editor");
h1("text-value");

const texteditor = document.querySelector('#text-editor');
const textvalue = document.querySelector('#text-value');
texteditor.addEventListener('keydown', ()=>{
textvalue.innerHTML = texteditor.value;
});
```

```html
<text-editor></text-editor>
<text-value></text-value>
```

This `build()` does one thing:- it selects the custom element, changes its tag type and assign a id of name of the custom tag and replaces it with the desired thing. It is working fine here. but if I code all the thing after the build function in a external .js file and then bind it to the html and run it, but it won't work. How can I resolve this? This is a very important for now.
Help and answers appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused. So your `querySelector` is working fine but the issue is when you move `build` to external file. Correct?

Comment: no brother, if you try doing it as you said, the query Selector will return null , and with id the query selector thing will not work in external file. We are not moving the build thing anywhere